# Add a node it its proper place (list will be in ascending order)

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to a add a node in its proper place (in ascending order). So when the user enters a number, then its value will be automatically stored in a memory location.

For example the user entered 2,5,3,6 and 4. Then these values will be stored in a memory location that is in ascending order, so that will be: 2,3,4,5, and 6. So the program will print out the values.

```
 //ADDING A NODE INTO A LIST
printf("Enter Number:");
scanf("%d",&temp);
while(temp>=0){
    newnode = malloc(sizeof(node)); //create a memory location with the size of the node
    //whatever data size is on the node, the 'sizeof' fcn will compute its size
    newnode->value= temp;
    newnode-> next = NULL;

    if (tail==NULL){
        head=newnode;
        tail=newnode;
    } else{
        tail->next=newnode;
        tail=newnode;

    }//end if

    printf("Enter Number:"); //Repeats the process until negative number is given
    scanf("%d",&temp);
}//endwhile
```

Then the program will display the values on the list

```
iter = head;
i=1;
while(iter!= NULL){
printf("i:%d -- value: %d\n",i, iter->value);
iter = iter-> next;
i++;
```

Comment: The program above will only store the values but not on its ascending order.

Comment: I will recommend to add more data about the problem and the solution you tried. This will help you in getting some help here. And please read this [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In order to make sure you insert nodes in ascending order you're likely going to have to walk the list every time you add a node until you find a place where it is <= the next value but >= the previous value and then insert it

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track, you know how to iterate linked list and add new nodes.

Now suppose user entered a value **val**, so while iterating your linked list you have to check whether **current node's value** is greater or smaller than **val**. Based on that you have to add **val** before or after your current node.

Answer (score 0):

**The only thing you have to do here is to traverse the linked list unless you find the correct position for the new node to be inserted**

Try to understand the code below, which solves your usecase and you can implement it on your own:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
     struct node*next;
}node;

void add(node**s,int num)
{
    node*temp;
    if(*s==NULL||num<(*s)->data)
    {
        temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data=num;
        temp->next=*s;
        *s=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=*s;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            if(temp->data<=num&&(temp->next==NULL || temp->next->data>num))
            {
                 node*temp1=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                 temp1->data=num;
                 temp1->next=temp->next;
                 temp->next=temp1;
                 return;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
        }
     }
 }

void traverse(node*s)
{
     while(s!=NULL)
     {
          printf("%d\t",s->data);
          s=s->next;
     }
}

void main()
{
     node*n=NULL;

     add(&n,2);
     add(&n,5);
     add(&n,3);
     add(&n,6);
     add(&n,4);
     traverse(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node * next;
} node;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("\nEnter Number:");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    //define root node here
    node root;
    root.value = 0;
    root.next  = NULL;

    while(i>=0){

        node * newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        newnode->value = i;
        newnode->next  = NULL;

        node * temp = &root;
        while (1) {
            if (temp->next == NULL) {
                temp->next = newnode;
                break;
            } else {
                if (temp->next->value > newnode->value) {
                    newnode->next = temp->next;
                    temp->next = newnode;
                    break;
                } else {
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("\nEnter Number:"); //Repeats the process until negative number is given
        scanf("%d",&i);
    }//endwhile

    node * temp = &root;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
        printf("%d,", temp->value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an answer that keeps things simple. It's not the most compact code and most like not the best performing code but some times keeping things simple are more important. And performance is not an issue here as you read in values from stdin.

But first notice that having a `tail` pointer for this list makes little sense. A `tail` pointer is good when you want to make fast insert at the end of a list. Since you want to make sorted inserts you'll have to iterate the list anyway and therefore wont get any benefit from the `tail` pointer.

So here is the simple example code - inline comments explains the code.

```
printf("Enter Number:");
scanf("%d",&temp);
while(temp>=0){
    newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->value= temp;
    newnode-> next = NULL;

    if (head==NULL)
    {
        // List was empty so just make newnode the head
        head=newnode;
    }
    else if (newnode->value <= head->value)
    {
        // The newnode has a value less or equal to current head
        // so the newnode can be inserted as head
        newnode->next = head;
        head = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        // Now iterate the list to find where to insert newnode
        node* p = head;
        while(p->next)   // Repeat until end-of-list is reached
        {
            if (newnode->value <= p->next->value)
            {
                // Insert the newnode between node p and node p->next
                newnode->next = p->next;
                p->next = newnode;

                // Stop the while-loop
                break;
            } 

            // Advance to next list element
            p = p->next;
        }

        // Check if newnode was inserted or end-of-list was reached
        if (p->next == NULL)
        {
            // end-of-list was reached so insert newnode at the end
            p->next = newnode;
        }
    }

    printf("Enter Number:");
    scanf("%d",&temp);
}
```

Some extra info:

Always check the value returned by `scanf` - in this case like:

```
// scanf("%d",&temp);  Dont do this but do:
if (scanf("%d",&temp) != 1)
{
    // Didn't get an int :(
    Add error handling here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is very simply to do. Write

```
node **current = &head;

while ( ( *current != NULL ) && !( temp < ( *current )->value ) )
{
    current = &( *current )->next;
}

newnode->next = *current;
if ( *current == NULL ) tail = newnode;
*current = newnode;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int main(void) 
{
    node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    const size_t N = 10;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        int value = rand() % N;

        node *newnode = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
        newnode->value = value;

        node **current = &head;

        while ( ( *current != NULL ) && !( value < ( *current )->value ) )
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }

        newnode->next = *current;
        if ( *current == NULL ) tail = newnode;
        *current = newnode; 
    }

    for ( node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->value );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
1 -> 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 9 -> NULL
```

You can move the code that inserts a node into a separate function.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int insert_node( node **head, node **tail, int value )
{
    node *newnode = malloc( sizeof( node ) );

    int success = newnode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newnode->value = value;

        node **current = head;

        while ( ( *current != NULL ) && !( value < ( *current )->value ) )
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }

        newnode->next = *current;
        if ( *current == NULL ) *tail = newnode;
        *current = newnode; 
    }       

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    const size_t N = 10;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        int value = rand() % N;
        insert_node( &head, &tail, value );     
    }

    for ( node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->value );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );

    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output might look like for example

```
4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 6 -> 7 -> 7 -> 8 -> 8 -> 9 -> 9 -> NULL
```

However it is better if you add one more structure as for example

```
typedef struct list
{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} list;
```

and write the function `insert_node` that deals with this structure.

Comment: Hello @Vlad from Moscow. Sorry to post it here, but there is no other way as I wanted to connect to you on LinkedIn and I don't have your full name

Comment: @Carisse Chen Ignore the down-voting. The code is correct. See the demonstrative program in my answer.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire See my profile. I do not take part at Linkedin.

Comment: Your profile is really interesting man. How do I connect to you if I need any specific help.